# Error in search operation using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii framework.I am doing search data in database.
But i got the error

**error**

```
 Unable to resolve the request "jobsite/error". (C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php:286).
```

My `controller` is `Sitecontroller.php`,`model` is `job`,my vie pages are `seach.php` and `search_result.php`.My `table` name is `jobs`.
//My codes are given below.
//Controller is `Sitecontroller.php`

```
 <?php
   class SiteController extends Controller
     {
     public function actionsearch()
  {
   $user_id = trim($_GET['id']);  
   $model = new Job ;
   if(isset($_POST['Job']))
      {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Job'];
        $title=$_POST['Job']['title'];
        $model=Job::model()->find(array('select'=>'*',"condition"=>"title like '%$title%'",));
        $number=count($model);
        if($number>0)
        {
          $this->redirect(array('site/search_result','model'=>$model));     
        }

      }
   $this->render('search',array('model' =>$model));
 }
   public function actionsearch_result()
  {
   $model = new Job ;
   $this->render('search_result',array('model' =>$model));
 }
     }
  ?>

//model-job.php
```

rules section

```
 <?php

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('title,key_skills','required'),
    );
}
```

?>

//view-search.php

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>false,
'htmlOptions' => array(),
    'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true
),
)); ?>
 <?php
 foreach(Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
 }
 ?>
   <div class="row">
   <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Keyword'); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'title'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'title'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search'); ?>
</div>
  <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
  </div>
```

//view-search_result.php

```
  <div style="float:right;margin-right:285px;">
  <h1>Search Jobs</h1>
 <table width="200" border="1">
 <tr>
 <td>SI No</td>
 <td>Title</td>
 <td>Key Skill</td>
  <td>Experince</td>
 </tr>
  <?php
foreach($model as $models)  
   { 
 ?>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><?php echo $models->title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $models->key_skills; ?></td
 ><td><?php echo $models->experience; ?></td
  ></tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Anybody help me?

Comment: Where is your error page. I think that the page jobsite/error doesn't exists.

Comment: search_result.php is my error page.

Comment: an in witch is your error action? Note: The error action is called if you're having a yyntax error. The action is set in the main config

Comment: my error mesg is "Unable to resolve the request "jobsite/error". (C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php:286)"

Comment: I think that you dont understand me. I hope that this link can help you to understand what i asked: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error

Answer (score 0):

You had the wrong error page setted in the main-config. (protected/config/main.php)

you should set an error action to the error handler (or reset it to a valid page).

```
'errorHandler'=>array(
    'errorAction'=>'site/error',
),
```

In the error.php (View) you need to have `<?php echo CHtml::encode($message); ?>` that the errrors will be printed.

Here you can find an explanation of the [Yii error handling](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error)

If you had implemented this, Yii will be able to show you the error resulting from the sql query.

Comment: new error is urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given    C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CUrlManager.php(440)

Comment: I had added that page above.